# Why does this opamp have a diode on v+

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, guitar-pedal

I was working on a layout for a guitar effect, and noticed on the schematic that 1 opamp has a 1N4148 diode on V+.   IC6 on the schematic below.

Given it has an internal power supply, I'm assuming this is not for polarity protection (guitar effects often run off external power supplies, and diodes are commonly placed on the input of V+)

Q1) What is the purpose of this diode

Q2) Would it matter if it was not there

Thanks for any assistance available.

EDIT:  SCHEM UPDATE, PREVIOUS INCORRECT

[image: PHASOR II SCHEMATIC]

Comment: It looks like there is an error in that schematic - IC6b pin 5 should not go just to a capacitor. That will not work. I suspect the capacitor should go to pin 6 and pin 5 should be grounded.

Comment: @KevinWhite Agreed... except that there is feedback from the output back to IC6A, which I'm still looking over.

Comment: Thank you - you are correct.  I found another schematic, where 5 is grounded and the cap is across pin 6 & 7

Comment: @jonk - It is never good just have an input just going to a capacitor - it will charge up due to bias current until the opamp saturates.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yeah. That's also been thoughts, too. It was just that I hadn't yet fully considered that feedback loop and I'm always open to questioning prior assumptions I have previously held when I see something new to me. (A comparator, for example, might switch its output and change the direction of the integration, periodically. I'm a hobbyist. So I have to always check myself. I spoke out loud on the idea that it may trigger a thought I wasn't currently having.)

Comment: _" I found another schematic"_ - where did you find it?

Comment: It appears to be part of a distortion circuit but the schematic is not complete enough to be sure.

Comment: @jonk - opamps and comparators generally have the bias current always in the same direction. The circuit round IC6 is a fairly common triangle wave oscillator. The second part is an integrator.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yup. I had spoken while still thinking things over. I'm not quite as fast as some. ;)

Comment: @BruceAbbott - I found an old service manual, and build docs for a clone.  https://www.pedalpcb.com/docs/PhaseII.pdf

Comment: Here's another one:- https://www.experimentalistsanonymous.com/diy/Schematics/Phasers/Mu-Tron%20Bi-phase%20page%201.gif

Answer (score 0):

Q1) The diode is there because it drops the Vdd on IC6 by about a volt (whatever the Vt of the diode is).  That means IC6.2 is only feeding a maximum of +8V into IC5.1

Q2) Will it matter?  I suspect so, but define "matter".  Guitar pedals like to throw diodes into random places because it causes or ameliorates "clipping" which creates non-linear effects on the output audio spectrum.